# How to share a Flux with a cached value, with cancelled when all subscribers are detached?

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun fluxCacheCancel() {
        val shared = Flux.interval(Duration.of(1, ChronoUnit.SECONDS))
            .doOnCancel { log.debug("parent cancelled") } // I want to call this!!
            .share()
            .cache(1)

        val child1 = shared
            .doOnNext { log.debug("child1 $it") }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())
            .subscribe()

        Thread.sleep(3500) // 0, 1, 2

        val child2 = shared
            .doOnNext { log.debug("child2 $it") }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())
            .subscribe()

        Thread.sleep(500)

        child1.dispose()
        Thread.sleep(3500) // 2(cached), 3, 4, 5, 6
        child2.dispose()

        Thread.sleep(1000)
    }
```

I want to share a Flux with a cached value, with cancelled when all subscribers are detached.

How to do it?

Without `.cache(1)`, doOnCancel called well.